# How to upload a file to google drive using python Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to upload a file sent by the user to my bot into the Google drive.
Here is my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import telegram
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler ,MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)




SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))



def file_handler(bot, update):
  file = bot.getFile(update.message.document.file_id)
  file.download(update.message.document.file_name)

    FILES = ((update.message.file_name, False),(update.message.file_name, True),)

    for filename, convert in FILES:
        metadata = {'title': filename}
        res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
                media_body=filename ).execute()
        if res:
            print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))



def error(bot, update, error):
  logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, error)

def main():
  updater = Updater(token='xxxxxxxxxx')
  dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
  dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document,file_handler))
  updater.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

By this code, I can download the files uploaded by the users to bot (without the google-api part).
But How can I upload these files to google drive...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure how you'll authorize it or how should it behave when uploading (using a general drive or you'll upload it on behalf of the user) or the mechanics of your app. Try checking this [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) there is a code for python.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to upload files from telegram to google drive by combining both `google-drive-api` and `telegram-bot-api`.

Here is the flow chart that depicts how the code works.

**bot.py**

```
def file_handler(bot, update):
  file = bot.getFile(update.message.document.file_id)
  file.download(update.message.document.file_name)

  FILES = ((update.message.document.file_name, False),(update.message.document.file_name, True),)

  for filename, convert in FILES:
      metadata = {'title': filename}
      res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
              media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
      if res:
          print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))
          # silentremove(filename) #if u want to remove upladed file from local 
          update.message.reply_text("Uploaded!")
```

[Telegram bot Google Drive API integration example](https://github.com/zume2020/Telegram-bot-Google-Drive)