# How to Connect a Telegram Bot to Google Drive on Python 3?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, telegram, google-api-python-client, python-telegram-bot

I'm learning Python and want to create a Telegram Bot to work with Google Drive.

The logic of the bot is the following:
**Step 1**. A telegram user clicks the button (or the link) in the chat selecting what file they want to get READ permission to;
**Step 2**. Then the bot asks for their Google Email Address and checks if the gmail address is valid;
**Step 3**. Then the bot connects to my Google Drive to the selected file and grants the READ permission to the provided gmail address;
**Step 4**. Finally, the bot replies to the user in the chat with the proper link to the file.

I looked through these guides and pages:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-installed.md#complete-example
- https://github.com/zume2020/Telegram-bot-Google-Drive/blob/master/bot.py
- [How to upload a file to google drive using python Telegram Bot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902463/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-using-python-telegram-bot-api)

However, nothing works yet and I see errors like `Authorization Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` or something about credentials which I inputted correctly based on the errors I got previously.

Please, direct me to the working examples and/or documentations I should read to create the bot I want. I'm at loss at the moment.

Thank you!

---

*Update 1 (2021-10-19)*

I managed to implement the **Step 1** with this code:

```py
from telegram import (
    Update,
    InlineKeyboardMarkup,
    InlineKeyboardButton,
)
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CallbackContext,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
)


def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    bot_reply = f'Howdy, {update.effective_user.first_name}.\nThis is the main menu.'
    update.message.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text=bot_reply,
        reply_markup=menuMarkup01()
    )


def menuMarkup01():
    keyboardMarkup = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Share File 1', callback_data='gdriveTestButton')],
    ]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboardMarkup)


def startCallbackHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query

    if query.data == 'gdriveTestButton':
        query.edit_message_text(text='Sharing the File 1 with you.', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([]))
        # Here the next function should be called that accepts
        # the user input if it's a valid gmail address or not,
        # and if it's not then the bot asks the user for a valid
        # gmail address again.

bot_token = '1234abcd'
updater = Updater(bot_token, use_context=True)

disp = updater.dispatcher
disp.add_handler(CommandHandler(command='start', callback=startCommand))
disp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(startCallbackHandler))

updater.start_polling(drop_pending_updates=True)
updater.idle()
```

---

*Update 2 (2021-10-19)*

The **Step 3** works with this code (merge this code with the code from the **Step 1**):

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def gdriveShare(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    if context.args:
        # I took the json file from my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) → IAM & Admin → Service Accounts:
        service_key_file = 'service_key.json'
        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(service_key_file, scopes=scope)

        driveV3 = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
        fileId = '1ZP1xZ0WaH8w2yaQTSx99gafNZWawQabcdVW5DSngavQ'  # My xlsx-file.
        permDict = driveV3.permissions().list(fileId=fileId, fields='permissions').execute()

        newGmailUser = context.args[0]
        permList = permDict['permissions']
        usersList = []
        # Creating a list of the current gmail addresses that already has access to the file:
        for i in range(len(permList)):
            usersList.append(permList[i].get('emailAddress'))
        if newGmailUser not in usersList:
            permNewBody = {
                'role': 'reader',
                'type': 'user',
                'emailAddress': newGmailUser,
            }
            driveV3.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, body=permNewBody).execute()
            bot_reply = f"""The file is now shared with this user:
{newGmailUser}\n
See the file here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZP1xZ0WaH8w2yaQTSx99gafNZWawQabcdVW5DSngavQ
"""
            update.message.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=bot_reply)
        else:
            bot_reply = f'The user {newGmailUser} already has access to the file.'
            update.message.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=bot_reply)
    else:
        bot_reply = f"""Please, provide a gmail address after the command.
Example:
/share testtest@gmail.com"""
        update.message.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=bot_reply)

# Here the bot takes the gmail address as the "context" argument after
# the command "/share". Example:
# /share testtest@gmail.com
disp.add_handler(CommandHandler("share", gdriveShare))
```

---

*Update 3 (2021-10-20)*

The **Step 2** and the **Step 4** are implemented here:
[How to trigger a conversation handler with the bot reply? [Telegram Bot] [Python] [python-telegram-bot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637349/how-to-trigger-a-conversation-handler-with-the-bot-reply-telegram-bot-python)

Now my bot logic is completed. Hooray!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the article on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More precisely, please clarify if your problem is with googled drive or with `python-telegram-bot`. Information on when these exceptions appear and their exact traceback is also crucial

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.